# iptables: change local source address if destination address matches

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a Linux machine (RHEL 6.7) with 2 IP's configured on a single NIC (eth1). The primary address, and therefore the address that all traffic appears to come from, is 10.0.0.23. The other is 10.0.0.160.

I am looking for a way to use iptables to change the source IP based on the destination address of a packet. Normally the traffic will 'go out on' 10.0.0.23, but say my packet is destined for 10.0.0.1, I want that packet to 'go out on' 10.0.0.160.

The reason for this is firewalls on the network that are out of my control. There are rules in place allowing traffic from 10.0.0.160 to 10.0.0.1, but not from 10.0.0.23 to 10.0.0.1.

I don't want all traffic to originate from 10.0.0.160, only that destined for 10.0.0.1.

I was looking at using the nat table and maybe a prerouting rule, but don't see a way to change the source address.
If it would help I could create an alias for eth1 (so there would be eth1 and eth1:0) but would like to see if there's a solution in the current config.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for wanting to do this with `iptables`? The behaviour you described is easily achieved by modifying the routing table.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are two different methods of achieving the desired behaviour:

## 1. Using iptables

The `SNAT` target in `iptables` allows the source address to be modified as you requested. The man page for [iptables-extensions](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) has this to say about `SNAT`:

> This  target  is only valid in the nat table, in the POSTROUTING and
>   INPUT chains,
>          and user-defined chains which are only called from  those  chains.   It  specifies
>          that  the  source address of the packet should be modified (and all future packets
>          in this connection will also be mangled), and rules should cease  being  examined.

Based on your question, the following rule will change the source address of packets destined for `10.0.0.1` to `10.0.0.160`:

```
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --destination 10.0.0.1/32 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.160
```

## 2. Using a static route

Alternatively, instead of an `iptables` rule, add a static route for the destination host to the routing table, using the following syntax:

```
$ ip route add <destination>/32 via <gateway> src <alias>
```

Based on the information you provided, you would use:

```
$ ip route add 10.0.0.1/32 via <gateway> src 10.0.0.160
```

Replace `<gateway>` with the actual IP address of your gateway, as this wasn't provided in your question.

Traffic destined for `10.0.0.1` will now originate from `10.0.0.160`. Any other traffic takes the default route, originating from `10.0.0.23`.

Comment: soulcake - there is no particular reason why I want to use iptables to accomplish this. Your option one works just fine, thank you. Your option two is not working for me, when I add your rule I can no longer ping my destination. So you have solved my problem, but I don't think I should mark the question answered since the rule doesn't work for me. Either way, many thanks.

Comment: @eliszka If you could post the output of `ip addr` for the interface you're working with I could possibly help you with the static route method. Other than that, I think the answer specifically addresses what you were requesting, and likely deserves an upvote at least?

Comment: I will mark it answered since, if you remove 'iptables' from the title it is in fact answered. Your routing solution works for me but the iptables rule does not.

Comment: @eliszka I misunderstood in that case. In your first comment you mentioned 'option two is not working', which I took to refer to the static route as this was labelled as the second option. You could try running `tcpdump -i <interface> 'icmp[icmptype] = icmp-echo'` on host `10.0.0.1`, and then run `ping 10.0.0.1` from host `10.0.0.160`. The `tcpdump` command will show you whether your ICMP request packets are at least reaching the host. Can you confirm? It could be the case that this traffic isn't making it through your firewall.

Comment: After applying your iptables rule I get 100% packet loss pinging 10.0.0.1 from 10.0.0.160, however the packets are making it to 10.0.0.1 per the `ICMP echo request` output I see running your tcpdump command on 10.0.0.1.

Comment: @eliszka I would rerun the tcpdump command with the `-n` flag—which displays IP addresses instead of hostnames—just to confirm that the echo request packets originate from `10.0.0.160` and not `10.0.0.23`. Then run `watch -n1 -d iptables -L -v` on host `10.0.0.1`, while pinging it from the other system, to monitor rule matches. You should see the counters incrementing in one second intervals. Can you identify a rule from this that may be responsible for the traffic being dropped?

Comment: It's also worth considering whether the iptables rules on `10.0.0.160` actually allow incoming ICMP traffic. The OUTPUT chain may be permitting ICMP traffic to pass out onto the network, but the INPUT chain may be explicitly dropping ICMP traffic, or have its default policy set to DROP without an explicit rule to allow ICMP traffic in. In either case, you wouldn't receive echo responses.

Comment: I've verified that the packets do originate from 10.0.0.160 and there are no iptables rules preventing the ICMP traffic. The INPUT chain explicitly ACCEPTs all icmp traffic. The default OUTPUT chain policy is ACCEPT.

Comment: Good to know about static route method! Now actually my packets take the IP of the gateway, how can I preserve the original IP address of them?