# Linux respond with source address of a virtual interface

Tags: network-interface, routing, dhcp

Hoping this is the correct forum.

I have a Linux (Centos 7) server with Quagga (for BGP) and DNSMASQ (for DHCP) installed. We are running DHCP services over BGP for redundancy.

Currently, the client is reaching out to the DHCP server via BGP ip address (10.10.12.12) and sending a DISCOVER packet. The DHCP server sees it and makes an OFFER, however the OFFER is not getting back to the client because the DHCP server is sending it back with a source address of the internal IP of the DHCP server (172.18.25.10 - You can see proof of this below in second tcpdump packet) and not the BGP ip address (10.10.12.12). 172.18.25.10 is being blocked by our firewall (and we do not want to open it).

How might I set the source address returning back to the client as the BGP address instead of the internal IP? I've been playing around with ip routing configurations but can't seem to get it right. Any ideas?

Routes

```
$ ip r
default via 172.18.25.1 dev ens256 proto static metric 100 
172.18.25.0/24 dev ens256 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.25.10 metric 100
```

Interfaces

```
$ ifconfig
ens256: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.18.25.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.18.25.255
    (truncated for brevity...)

lo:10: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 10.10.12.12  netmask 255.255.255.255
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
```

Virtual Interface config for lo:10

```
DEVICE=lo:10
IPADDR=10.10.12.12
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
ONBOOT=yes
NAME=lo10
```

DHCP server tcpdump

```
17:44:11.833026 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 62, id 4923, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 388)
192.168.69.1.67 > 10.10.12.12.67: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from a8:60:b6:0c:49:cd, length 360, hops 1, xid 0xad97213f, secs 8, Flags [none] (0x0000)
  Gateway-IP 192.168.69.1
  Client-Ethernet-Address a8:60:b6:0c:49:cd
  Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
    Magic Cookie 0x63825363
    DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Discover
    Parameter-Request Option 55, length 10: 
      Subnet-Mask, Classless-Static-Route, Default-Gateway, Domain-Name-Server
      Domain-Name, Option 119, Option 252, LDAP
      Netbios-Name-Server, Netbios-Node
    MSZ Option 57, length 2: 1500
    Client-ID Option 61, length 7: ether a8:60:b6:0c:49:cd
    Lease-Time Option 51, length 4: 7776000
    Hostname Option 12, length 9: "tests-MBP"
    Agent-Information Option 82, length 57: 
      Circuit-ID SubOption 1, length 42: ToR-vc.corp.fake01:ge-0/0/20.0:dhcp-test-69
      Remote-ID SubOption 2, length 11: ge-0/0/20.0

17:44:11.833196 IP (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 4315, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 394)
172.18.25.10.67 > 192.168.69.1.67: [bad udp cksum 0xcc4d -> 0xe7d1!] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 366, hops 1, xid 0xad97213f, secs 8, Flags [none] (0x0000)
  Your-IP 192.168.69.230
  Server-IP 172.18.25.10
  Gateway-IP 192.168.69.1
  Client-Ethernet-Address a8:60:b6:0c:49:cd
  Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
    Magic Cookie 0x63825363
    DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Offer
    Server-ID Option 54, length 4: 172.18.25.10
    Lease-Time Option 51, length 4: 300
    RN Option 58, length 4: 150
    RB Option 59, length 4: 262
    Subnet-Mask Option 1, length 4: 255.255.255.0
    BR Option 28, length 4: 192.168.69.255
    Default-Gateway Option 3, length 4: 192.168.69.1
    Domain-Name-Server Option 6, length 4: 172.18.25.10
    Domain-Name Option 15, length 13: "example.com"
    Agent-Information Option 82, length 57: 
      Circuit-ID SubOption 1, length 42: ToR-vc.corp.fake01:ge-0/0/20.0:dhcp-test-69
      Remote-ID SubOption 2, length 11: ge-0/0/20.0
```

Comment: Not exactly necessarily related to your question, but is there a reason you're using a non-loopback address on a (virtual) loopback interface?  Seeing a `lo*` interface with an address outside of 127.0.0.0/8 struck me as very odd indeed.

Comment: see comments below

Answer (score 1):

Based on [iptables: change local source address if destination address matches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243451/iptables-change-local-source-address-if-destination-address-matches) I was able to find a solution with a simple ip route added.

```
ip route add 192.168.69.1/32 via 172.18.25.1 src 10.10.12.12
```

or

```
ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 via 172.18.25.1 src 10.10.12.12
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well this is a problem with dnsmasq, the software offer a few solutions to your problem:
interface to force listening of a specified interface e.g:

```
interface=lo:10
```

no-dhcp-interface to disable the distribution of DHCP on this interface e.g:

```
no-dhcp-interface=ens256
```

listen-address, looking like interface but specifying a binding IP instead e.g:

```
listen-address=10.10.12.12
```

[From the dnsmasq documentation](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) :

```
-i, --interface=<interface name> Listen only on the specified interface(s). 
Dnsmasq automatically adds the loopback (local) interface to the list of 
interfaces to use when the --interface option is used. If no --interface or 

-2, --no-dhcp-interface=<interface name>
Do not provide DHCP or TFTP on the specified interface, but do provide DNS 
service.

-a, --listen-address=<ipaddr>
Listen on the given IP address(es). Both --interface and --listen-address 
options may be given, in which case the set of both interfaces and addresses 
is used. Note that if no --interface option is given, but --listen-address 
is, dnsmasq will not automatically listen on the loopback interface. To 
achieve this, its IP address, 127.0.0.1, must be explicitly given as a -- 
listen-address option.
```

Comment: Tried it. dnsmasq doesn't see the traffic at all. It seems to only pickup on the ens256 interface, there is no OFFER, only the DISCOVER. Regardless, not sure that would help resolve the issue of setting source address as the lo:10 interface address (10.10.12.12)

Comment: Is it possible that trying to use the loopback interface for non-localhost traffic is part of the problem?

Comment: Typically it's assigned to the loopback with BGP because a loopback interface always remains up and keeps BGP peering established as long as there is a link available to reach the peer.